# Python - Correct way of closing ogr.DataSource() objects

Tags: python, ogr, python-2.7, pycharm

I learned that I need to close objects that I open, usually using a `with open():` statement that does the closing for you after leaving it. With GDAL/OGR, this does not work and objects must be closed manually. In GDAL, this works by

```
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open(MY_FILE, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
ds = None
```

With OGR, I found two ways to do that:

```
from osgeo import ogr
ds = ogr.Open(MY_FILE)
ds = None

# outputs:
# R6025
# - pure virtual function call

# crashes the debugger

ds.Destroy()

# same
```

While it seems to work fine with both methods when I run the full script, it crashes my debugger when I run it in debug mode (PyCharm, in my case). In the console, `ds = None` seems to work, while `ds.Destroy()` crashes the whole console with the `Pure virtual function call` output.

Is this specific to PyCharm or am I doing something essentially wrong?

Comment: At least ds.Destroy is much used in GDAL autotests, for example https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_sqlite.py.

Comment: Tried it in windows console and QGIS Python console, where it seems to work fine. Looks like this might be specific to PyCharm, asked the same question there: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010010259-PyCharm-console-crashes-with-R6025-Pure-virtual-function-call-

Comment: Interesting, user document in https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html suggests that destroy should not be used.

Comment: That hinted to this: if I do `ds = ogr.Open(MY_FILE)` and `lyr = ds.GetLayer()`, I do not only need to set `ds = None`, but also `lyr = None`. This keeps the debugger and the console alive!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the problem is related to PyCharm. I have tested it in Anaconda/Spyder and VS Code without a problem.

As I recall properly, the only way of 'closing' a file with GDAL is with

```
from osgeo import ogr
file = ogr.Open(MY_FILE)
file = None
```